# Is CodeRush Xpress compatible with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coderush-xpress

Is CodeRush Xpress (the free edition of CodeRush) compatible with Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Why don't you search on their support forums? Found [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q426518) in two minutes

Comment: That refers to the full paid version, not XPress. I had already looked on their site but couldn't find any information regarding the free Xpress edition currently only available for vs2008/2010.

Comment: **WARNING**: I just foolishly accepted an 'update' of CodeRush Xpress, which promptly replaced my fully working unlimited version with a 30-day trial version. And I now discover that I didn't have a back-up of the original installer :(

Comment: Oh good, found my backup of the installer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official response from Alex Skorkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12764153/238753) has been that it is not supported:

> I'm afraid that CodeRush Xpress is not going to be available in Visual Studio 2012.

However, [it actually is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760990/is-coderush-xpress-compatible-with-visual-studio-2012/21173982#comment17797351_12764153) and [has been supported](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q441775). Just [download](http://go.devexpress.com/CodeRushX.aspx) and install it as normal. [A staff member has eventually confirmed this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q478273#comment-77535753-e3e3-11e2-bf4c-f0bf97cd2e09):

> The latest version of CodeRush Xpress (11.2.13) supports Visual Studio 2012.

The [official page](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) also bears the following badge:

> FULL SUPPORT for Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that CodeRush Xpress is not going to be available in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: That's a shame. Do you know the reasons why?

Comment: Why a shame? This is how the free version is designed.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I follow. As far as I'm aware, there are free editions of CodeRush for vs2008/2010. Is it unreasonable to question if there will be a 2012 offering? If there won't be then that's fine, you've already answered my question.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. Of course it is reasonable question to ask if the free CodeRush Xpress version supports Visual Studio 20012. The problem is that currently, there are no plans to support this version of Visual Studio. This is a restriction of the free version of CodeRush. It supports Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 and CSharp and Visual Basic languages only.

Comment: I just installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and the latest version of CodeRush Xpress, and it definitely **does** work.

Comment: I with Sam.  I was able to download the newest version and the installer automatically integrated it with VS 2012.  There doesn't seem to be an Extension yet, that is all.  You can still download the installer.  I go the installer here http://go.devexpress.com/CodeRushX.aspx

Comment: There's a difference between DevExpress the company "supporting" a version of Visual Studio, and CodeRush XPress the product "supporting" (working with) a version.  "Supporting" for DevExpress means that DevExpress will provide technical support, and use resources to test/verify features with supported versions of VS, which is what they are saying they will not do.  This doesn't mean the product won't continue to work with future versions.